# Cosine is not calculating the exact value

Tags: c++, trigonometry

I was working on a little something and i needed the cosine 
I included `math.h` library in order to get `cosine` function 
after printing the result it turns out that `cosine` differs on my program than what it was on calculator 
for example `Cos(40)` on calculator was 0.70710678118 but in the program it was 0.766044 
and this is how I was calculating the cosine `cos(some variable*PI/180)`
and because of that all my results are going wrong 
Isn't it supposed to be the same result? why all these stuff happening 
and how to solve it?

Comment: First guess: radians vs. degrees?

Comment: cos(40) is 0.766044... You put it in your calculator wrong

Comment: 0.76604444311 is the correct value.

Comment: in google calculator it is 0.70710678118 .. and i just tried to code a program that calculate some physics stuff for me the answers on book is different because the cosine is being calculated different

Comment: 0.70710678118 is cos(45 degrees), not 40.

Comment: `cos(40 / 180*pi) == 0.76604444311`

Comment: for the convert between radians and degrees check this out http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/cos/

Comment: You have `some_variable * PI/180` -- `PI/180` is backwards for degrees to radians.

Comment: @Ike it's the same thing

Comment: @interjay Oh you're right, brain fart.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know where your values come from, but `0.70710678118` is an approximation of `sqrt(2)/2` that is sin or cos of π/4 or 45°. So except in a *very* weird units, `cos(40)` cannot be `sqrt(2)/2`.

BTW in my own calculator, `cos(40) = 0.76604444311897803520239265055542` in degrees mode.